# C# wpf dataGrid Items.Add not change data value run on backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf

```
foreach (dynamic myrank in json.data)
{
    Rankdata Keyrank = new Rankdata();
    Keyrank.rankOn = myrank.search_volume.ToString();
    Keyrank.rankKeyword = myrank.keyword.ToString();
    Keyrank.rankSearchVolume = myrank.search_volume.ToString();
    Keyrank.rankBidPrice = myrank.recommend_price.ToString();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
    {
        dataGridRank.Items.Add(Keyrank);

    }));
}

public class Rankdata
{
    public string rankOn { get; set; }
    public string rankKeyword { get; set; }
    public string rankSearchVolume { get; set; }
    public string rankBidPrice { get; set; }
}
```

first data show on datagrid all row
but i add  sleep `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);`
to loop foreach data is changed but it slowly

Comment: What do you mean by "slowly"? You should see one item being added each second if you sleep for one second in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way to add elements.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                       dataGridRank.Items.Add(Keyrank);
                    }));
```

Comment: Thank you sir
i change to  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke